# Why NSNumber truncate double value?

Tags: objective-c

**it's function about i talked**

```
- (void)getAddressFromLatLon:(double)pdblLatitude withLongitude:    (double)pdblLongitude
            {
                NSDictionary *adressWithLtLn = @{ 
                    @"latitude":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pdblLatitude],
                    @"longtitude":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pdbllongtitude]};
              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"userAddress" object:adressWithLtLn];
        }
```

**listener:**

```
- (void)didGetAddressNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if ([notification object]!=nil){
    NSDictionary *nott = [notification object];
    if( nott!=NULL ){
         currentAddress=nott;
    }
   }}
```

**button for action**

```
 - (IBAction)pressButtonOrder:(id)sender {
            if ([currentAddress count]>0){
                 Order *order = [[Order alloc]init];
                [order sendOrder:[currentAddress objectForKey:@"latitude"] source_lng:[currentAddress objectForKey:@"longtitude"]];
             }
            }
```

**and sender**

```
 -(void)sendOrder:(NSNumber*)source_lat source_lng:(NSNumber*)source_lng;
        {
            API *api=[[API alloc]init] ;

            NSDictionary *params = @{
                                     @"imei":[api getUDID] ,
                                     @"source_lat":source_lat,
                                     @"source_lng":source_lng
                                     };


            AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

            [manager POST:@"http://" parameters:params
                      success:
                  ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
             {
              // some code…    

             }


                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
             {
                  NSLog(@"Error JSON: %@", error);
                   }
             ];
            }
```

If values are:

```
    pdblLatitude=  48.514266999999997
    pdblLongitude= 32.256956000000002
```

in result i have:

```
FORM/POST PARAMETERS

    source_lat: 48.514267
    source_lng: 32.256956
```

Comment: Show how you displayed the result.

Comment: i see that in Debug window screenshot [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmrl6n1ujg2xd74/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-06-10%2017.53.26.png?dl=0

Comment: The debugger only shows the first few significant digits for a floating point number.

Comment: @rmaddy but debugger show pdblLatitude and pdblLongitude all number

Comment: I misspoke. It's the default implementation of the `description` method of `NSNumber` that only shows a limited number of significant digits.

Comment: @rmaddy give me few minutes, i will try to check with some post json

Comment: double y = [x doubleValue]; // Is this how you got the result?  Or simply doing a @"%@", x ?  Makes a big difference.  I believe 'y' and 'pdblLatitude' should match, but the string output might not.

Comment: @rmaddy same problem. on my server i catch json and i have truncated value "source_lat=48.514267&source_lng=32.256956"

Comment: @Numfirst And now the keys are different to those shown in your code.  So now please show the code that creates that URL/JSON/Whatever.

Comment: @Droppy you can see it)

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
- (void)getAddressFromLatLon:(double)pdblLatitude withLongitude:(double)pdblLongitude
{
    NSDictionary *adressWithLtLn = @{ 
        @"latitude":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pdblLatitude],
        @"longtitude":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pdblLatitude]};
                                                     ^^^^^^^^
}
```

You meant to store longitude didn't you...

**EDIT**: This doesn't cover the truncation aspect, however the results you show are strings, so something else is happening to the values that you have not disclosed yet.

Comment: While that may be an issue, it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: its not important. Question about trancation

Comment: @Numfirst Please tell my why the results you show are strings.

Comment: @Droppy Because he logged the dictionary?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Perhaps.  I'd like the OP to tell us in detail.